# How to open an ImageView resource with Android's default Gallery application?

Tags: android, android-intent, imageview, gallery

I have looked around for a good way to open the resource of my ImageView using the default Gallery application, but have come up empty. Now I am no longer looking for a good way, but just a way that will work period. I am using Android's latest API and I have tried many different possible solutions available on Stack and other resources. I am basically trying to piggyback the pan and zoom functionality of the Gallery application by using it to open the current image of my slideshow (basically an ImageView) when clicked. I have tried using .setData, .setDataAndType, several different URI parsing methods, intent filters, etc. I have even tried setting up a resolver to prevent the code from executing if a null value was returned which seemed to work. This points me to believe that perhaps something is not resolving correctly? Here is my code:

```
  public void onImageClicked(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri imgUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.mypackagename/" + images[current]);
    intent.setDataAndType(imgUri, "image/*");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

images[current] is of type Integer and returns the resource value of the current image in my slideshow. Ex: R.drawable.myImage1

Note: com.mypackagename is just a censor. I have the actual package name  in my original code.

Errors:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
>
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>
> Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=android.resource://com.mypackagename/2130837662 typ=image/* }

Answer (score 2):

> How to open an ImageView resource with Android's default Gallery application?

There are thousands of Android device models. There are hundreds of "default Gallery application" implementations distributed on those device models. There is no single "default Gallery application", and your code has little to do with a "Gallery application".

> I am basically trying to piggyback the pan and zoom functionality of the Gallery application

There is no requirement for all `ACTION_VIEW` activities that accept images as content to support pan and zoom. If you want pan and zoom, use a library.

> This points me to believe that perhaps something is not resolving correctly?

Few apps bother supporting the `android.resource` scheme.

Your best solution for serving a resource to third-party apps is to use a `ContentProvider`. That could be [my `StreamProvider`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider), which provides some support for serving resources "out of the box". Or, it could be your own `ContentProvider` implementation.

Comment: Good Answer! Roll your own ContentProvider for your image data and just send out an ACTION_VIEW Intent. There is not more to it, but the receiving application might not look like what you wanted at all.

Comment: Thanks for the help! This is my first time creating an Android application. I am learning Java and the Android library as I go. I'll give it a go and see what I can come up with.